# Can't get API results using search bar

Tags: javascript, function, api, search, searchbar

I am trying to get a user's input from a search bar, and use it to get the drink information from a cocktail API, but I am not getting the results back.
If I use a real value for example, Margarita, instead of the placeholder ${drinkName} in my query URL I do get the data I'm looking for in the object form I'm looking for, but something about how I'm getting/using the user input is wrong. I do get the user's input from the search in the console when I console log drinkName, but it doesn't seem to pass that into the searchByName function, and console logging cocktail after the searchByName function returns my empty cocktail object.

```
let cocktail = {};

const searchByName = (drinkName) => {
    fetch(`https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=${drinkName}`)
    .then(
        function(response) {
        if (response.status !== 200) {
            console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
            response.status);
            return data;
            
        }
        response.json().then(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            getDrinkName(data);
            getIngredients(data);
            getDirections(data);
            getImage(data);
            buildCocktail(data);
            console.log(cocktail);
        });
        }
    )
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
    });
}

const getImage = (data) => {
    const imageUrl = (data.drinks[0].strDrinkThumb);
    return imageUrl;
}

const getDrinkName = (data) => {
    const name = (data.drinks[0].strDrink);  
    return name;
}

const getIngredients = (data) => {
    let ingredientList = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < 16; i++) {
        if (data.drinks[0][`strIngredient${i}`] == null){
            break;
        } else {
            const ingredients = ((data.drinks[0][`strMeasure${i}`]) + ': ' + data.drinks[0][`strIngredient${i}`]);
            ingredientList.push(ingredients);
        }
    }
    return ingredientList;
}

const getDirections = (data) => {
    const directions = (data.drinks[0].strInstructions);
    return directions;
}

const buildCocktail = (data) => {
    cocktail.image = getImage(data);
    cocktail.name = getDrinkName(data);
    cocktail.ingredients = getIngredients(data);
    cocktail.directions = getDirections(data);
    console.log(cocktail);    
}

$("#search").keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which === 13) {
        const drinkName = $('#search').val();
        console.log(drinkName);
        searchByName(drinkName);      
        console.log(cocktail);
    } 
});
```

Comment: It's expected that logging the `cocktail` variable immediately after initiating the Ajax call doesn't return results because it's an asynchronous operation. Do all the other console.logs show the correct data?

Comment: it should pass, console.log inside the searchbyname function, and see if there are some extra spaces and if you get the correct word